# Python PPTX - How to set chart axis number format and range

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I'm trying to accommodate a Bar Chart Y axis with a range from 0 to 1 with 1 decimal place like: 1.2 for tick labels:

I can set it to start at 0 with:

```
 Thisvalue_axis.minimum_scale = 0
```

And I can set the top value with:

```
 Thisvalue_axis.major_unit = 1
```

But the intermediate tick labels are not showing

here is my code:

```
Thisvalue_axis = ThisChart.value_axis
Thisvalue_axis.minimum_scale = 0
Thisvalue_axis.major_unit = 1
Thisvalue_axis.minor_tick_mark = XL_TICK_MARK.OUTSIDE
Thisvalue_axis.has_minor_gridlines = True
```

Is it possible to Make the values between 0 and 1 display and set the numberformat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set the top value by using:

```
value_axis.maximum_scale = 1
```

And then set the major unit to 0.1 or 0.2 or whatever suits:

```
value_axis.major_unit = 0.1
```

This particular example would show 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ... 1.0 as the tick mark labels.

Another look results from setting the major unit as 1 and setting the minor unit to 0.1 (or whatever you like). This would generally show a more prominent tick mark for the major unit and a less prominent one for the minor unit. Note however that tick labels only appear on the major tick marks.

The number format is set using the `TickLabels` object available on `Axis.tick_labels`:

```
value_axis.tick_labels.number_format = '0.0'
```